# отключить eval в php

Tags: php

как выключить eval  без Suhosin?
как можно защититься от использования

Comment: В php.ini есть свойство `disable_functions`, почитайте о нем подробнее

Comment: eval не является функцией

Comment: Кажется, никак - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1865020/php-how-to-disable-dangerous-functions#:~:text=eval()%20is%20technically%20not,essential%20part%20of%20site%20setup. Но может уже и читали

Comment: @DaemonHK читал уже.